# Why change the ending of Inferno from the novel?

Tags: ending, book-adaptation, inferno

** SPOILER warning for anyone who has not watched the movie or read the book **

In the novel, at the end, it is revealed that the virus was never meant to kill anyone, but instead made a part of the world's population infertile, which is quite a good ending in my opinion. It provides a solution to the problem of over population, while not killing anyone. There couldn't have been a better ending. Also actually releasing the virus way before the alleged time made a lot of sense and the fact that almost everyone has the virus at the end provides a sort of meaningful conclusion.

In the movie, the virus was in fact going to kill a lot of people and paints Zobrist as a terrorist. Also the ending seems incomplete as the problem still stands at the end, earth is still doomed.

So why would they change such a good ending and replace it with a much poorer one? Did the idea of a part of population infertile seemed a little controversial to the Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, the ending in the book was too drawn out and "wasn't cinematic" in terms of keeping the audience engaged.

According to an [interview](http://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/inferno/44654/exclusive-inferno-ron-howard-talks-about-changing-the-ending) with director Ron Howard:

> "My recollection is, Langdon wasn't really actively involved," Howard
>   told us. "It was so complicated and not really movie-ish. He got [to
>   Istanbul] and it had already been released. And so now, the upshot
>   was, well, half the population has this thing, and we don't quite know
>   who has it, and we don't know what's going to happen. [Sienna Brooks]
>   kind of runs away and Langdon chases her down and says, 'How could you
>   have done this?' And then he convinces Sinskey [head of the World
>   Health Organisation] to hire her to help seek an antidote. The kicker
>   is, not everyone's going to die; it's not instant death, it's a
>   fertility plague. And so, interesting, and intellectually intriguing,
>   and we missed it on that level. But it's very drawn out, and I can
>   imagine staging those scenes and a movie audience sitting and kind of
>   saying, 'How many endings are we going to have?'"
>
> The decision was therefore made to come up with a more explosive
>   conclusion - one that would require less exposition while giving
>   Langdon more to do. "The feeling was, that ending worked great for a
>   novel, but the complexity of it required a tremendous amount of
>   explanation. I think I felt like that was something we got bogged down
>   with a little bit in the previous movies, and when we found a way of
>   narrowing the focus of the third act, it felt more satisfying on a
>   movie level."

The author of the novel, Dan brown, was also apparently on-board with the change, and summed it up quite succinctly in an [interview](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1578939/inferno-ending-why-dan-brown-was-ok-with-the-movies-big-change):

> Anytime you're going to adapt a novel into a movie, a movie that is
>   not 25 hours long, some things are going to have to be simplified. I
>   know that the novel had a subtle, ambiguous ending. This was much more
>   direct, right to the point of it.